# Unequal axes of two plots

Tags: matlab, plot

In this

[image: figure]

I have two plots. What I should change to make the

axis like :

[image: figure 2].

```
contour(x,y,f);
hold on
plot( gX,  gY, 'r.','markersize',10); 
hold on
axis equal;
```

Comment: [**`ylim`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html)

Comment: @SardarUsama thank you

Comment: You can plot the mean and median of the red-dots to indicate outliers that are not visible from the cropped graph (you know, for the sake of not occluding any data in science =) )